# React Native navigation shared header element

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm working with react native and react-navigation I would like to accomplish following:

I have one component Person details, where I receive some data from API: avatar, license, city

In that component I have 2 buttons that goes to separate page.

But I have a component named  that is shared among all 3 of them

So when in first component **PersonDetails** where I recieve that data that is shared among those components.

Those props I receive in first Component Person Details I would like them to be shared among **PersonExtended** & **PersonLocation** but without passing them as props,
since avatar image is base64 and can be big.

So is there any other way how this can be done ?

**Person Details:**

```
export const PersonDetails = ({navigation, route}) => {


  /** Get user ID From parameters **/
  const {userId} = route.params;

  /** Redux selectors **/
  const {person = null, loading = true} = useSelector(state => state.vehicles);


  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();




  /**
   * Mounted hook, loads vehicle info
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(userActions.getUser({userId}));
  }, []);


  /**
   * Handle navigaton between card
   * @param {string} routeName
   */
  const handleNavigation = (routeName) => {
        navigation.navigate(routeName, {userId, 
        userInfo:
            {
              carAvatar: person.avatar,
              licencePlate: person.licencePlate,
              city: person.city
            }
        });
  };

  /**
   * Handle Click on X button in right corner
   */
  const handleBackNavigation = () => {
    navigation.goBack();
  };

  if (loading) {
    return <AnimatedLoader />;
  }
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, paddingBottom: insets.bottom}}>
      {/* Top header  */}
      <PersonInfo
        carAvatar={person.avatar}
        licencePlate={person.licencePlate}
      />
      {/* Top header  */}
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Button
            title={'extended info'} leftIcon="information-outline"
            onPress={() => handleNavigation('PersonExtendedDetails')} />
           <Button
            title={'location'} leftIcon="information-outline"
            onPress={() => handleNavigation('PersonLocation')} />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};


export default PersonDetails;
```

**Person Extended:**

```
export const PersonExtended = ({navigation, route}) => {


  /** Get user ID From parameters **/
  const {userId} = route.params;

  /** Redux selectors **/
  const {personExtended = null, loading = true} = useSelector(state => state.personExtended);


  const dispatch = useDispatch();





  /**
   * Mounted hook, loads vehicle info
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(userActions.getUserExended({userId}));
  }, []);
  

  /**
   * Handle Click on X button in right corner
   */
  const handleBackNavigation = () => {
    navigation.goBack();
  };

  if (loading) {
    return <AnimatedLoader />;
  }
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      {/* Top header  */}
      <PersonInfo
        carAvatar={person.avatar}
        licencePlate={person.licencePlate}
      />
      {/* Top header  */}
     <View>
       <Text> USER Location { personLocation.locationName } </Text>
     </View>
    </View>
  );
};


export default PersonExtended;
```

**Person Location:**

```
export const UserLocation = ({navigation, route}) => {


  /** Get user ID From parameters **/
  const {userId} = route.params;

  /** Redux selectors **/
  const {personLocation = null, loading = true} = useSelector(state => state.location);


  const dispatch = useDispatch();





  /**
   * Mounted hook, loads vehicle info
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(userActions.getUserLocation({userId}));
  }, []);
  

  /**
   * Handle Click on X button in right corner
   */
  const handleBackNavigation = () => {
    navigation.goBack();
  };

  if (loading) {
    return <AnimatedLoader />;
  }
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      {/* Top header  */}
      <PersonInfo
        carAvatar={person.avatar}
        licencePlate={person.licencePlate}
      />
      {/* Top header  */}
     <View>
       <Text> USER Location { personLocation.locationName } </Text>
     </View>
    </View>
  );
};


export default UserLocation;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the redux state to access the stored user's information like avatar and etc. in both other screens like you are getting on the first screen to show it.

for ex.

**Person Extended:**

```
const {person} = useSelector(state => state.vehicles);
```

**Person Location:**

```
const {person} = useSelector(state => state.vehicles);
```

-------**OR**-------

Create a file and export default class as below:

export default class Person {
static imageData = ''; // store image base64 data here..
}

Now just import the class in the screen where you are fetching the user data and assign the base64 image data to imageData static variable.

Like:

```
import Person from './Person';
Person.imageData = 'image/base64&...'
```

Usage

```
import Person from './Person';
<Image source={{uri: Person.imageData }} />
```

Comment: That would work but I'm trying not to use the store :/

Comment: Then you can have to create a static class and assign the avatar image to the static class variable so you can easily access them anywhere

Comment: How would I do that, could you share with me short example :)

Comment: @Loki, I have updated the answer please have a look.